# Set tableview to top and screenshot the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which one of it's cells at the bottom have a button which has to take a screenshot of the whole screen and the whole content of the table view.

I manage to screenshot at it with the following code

```
@objc func shareReceipt(sender:UIButton){


    self.receiptVC.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)



    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(receiptVC.tableView.contentSize
        , false, scale);

    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot!, nil, nil, nil)


}
```

The Problem I'm having is that when the screenshot is taken, the tableview is showing the last cells (with the share button).
I believe that happens because when I execute

```
self.receiptVC.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

the UI is not updated on time for when I screenshot at it.

My question is... what can I do to update de UI (set table view to top) and then screenshot it?

Comment: use `scrollToRow` with **GCD**

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: `dispatch_after` works for this scenario... did you tried it?

Comment: No... not yet... looking into it right now... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, when you click on the button scroll to top row and in the dispatch after closure write down your screenshot related code with the dispatch time 1 second. You get many examples for dispatch after.

Comment: That kinda worked! the tableview did scrolled to the top and the screenshot got it right! the problem is that the tableview is cutted on the botton, but now it might be a problem with my print screen code.

Comment: as soon as I get it right I'll post the solution